# I just cant figure out Project Plugin in VIM. Please help me #2

Tags: vim, plugins, project, text-editor

I am trying to use VIM for some programming :)

I think I have set it up correctly so I can see project window after :Project

My setting is:

```
    1 Xinxii=/var/www/xinxii/public_html CD=. flags=r
    2 {
    3     Controller Files=includes/controllers CD=. {
    4         AuthorController.class.php
    5     }
    6 }
```

When I click onto AuthorController.class.php it will open:
/AuthorController.class.php

instead of:
/var/www/xinxii/public_html/includes/controllers/AuthorController.class.php

What do I do wrong?

Thanks

---

Environment:

Linux 2.6.39.1
Vim 7.3.35
Vimproject 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the parent project entry's opening curly brace on to the same line as the description and flags:

```
Xinxii=/var/www/xinxii/public_html CD=. flags=r {
    Controller Files=includes/controllers CD=. {
        AuthorController.class.php
    }
}
```